# Download JFXtras 8.0-r5 or 8.0-r6

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I am trying to download the latest build of **[JFXtras](http://jfxtras.org/)** (i want the .jar file) but i can't find it.

For 8.0-r6 i can see some `.jar.soc` `.jar.asc` what are those files? https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/jfxtras/jfxtras-all/

For 8.0-r5  a jar exists but it is empty it has only Meta-Inf http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/jfxtras/jfxtras-all/

How to download the jar or build it?And what are those other files there?I haven't seen them again that's why i am asking..

**Problem Converting Project to Maven:**
[image: Image 1][image: Image 2]

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you with the Eclipse related problems, I'm not using it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The .jar.asc files contain a PGP signature.

To make maven download the jar from maven central, add the dependency to `pom.xml`, e.g.

```
   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.jfxtras</groupId>
           <artifactId>jfxtras-all</artifactId>
           <version>8.0-r5</version>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>
```

Or grab the jars manually from http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/jfxtras/ and add them to your project.

If you want to use the bleeding edge snapshot (currently 8.0r6-SNAPSHOT), you'll need to add the sonatype repository to your pom like

```
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>snapshots-repo</id>
      <name>Sonatype Snapshots</name>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

And add the current snapshot to the dependencies, e.g.

```
   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.jfxtras</groupId>
           <artifactId>jfxtras-all</artifactId>
           <version>8.0-r6-SNAPSHOT</version>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>
```

But be aware that they're development versions (unstable), and their availability in that location can be temporary.

To download the -SNAPSHOT jars manually, you go to the [sonata snapshot repository](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/jfxtras/), choose the jfxtras package that you want to download, and scroll down to find the jar.  They're simply not keeping all the older snapshots.

Comment: what is pom?I had not used this before some explain would be gratefull.The projects i have builded always used .jar files.

Comment: From maven.apache.org, *A [Project Object Model or POM](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html) is the fundamental unit of work in Maven. It is an XML file that contains information about the project and configuration details used by Maven to build the project. It contains default values for most projects.*  Are you using NetBeans by any chance?

Comment: I am using eclipse.

Comment: Too bad, don't have that now.  Was already taking a screenshot how to do it in NetBeans ;)  Go to the root folder of your project, see any `pom.xml` ?

Comment: I have found for javaFX 2 http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/jfxtras/jfxtras-labs/ but they are javaFX2 fff.... too bad :)

Comment: from the pom file i would have a jar file at the end?

Comment: Right-click on the project in the eclipse package explorer, choose "Configure", and "Convert to Maven project", accept the defaults in the popup window. It will create a basic pom file for you and open it. Click on the "Dependencies" tab at the bottom of the editor, the "Add" and add the values from the xml snippet in the answer. Save it and it will download the jar for you and put it in the correct location for your project to see it.

Comment: @James_D i have to download the .pom or .jar?Cause the .jar has only Meta-Inf inside.Also why JFXtras doesn't release standalone .jar like they have for javafx 2?

Comment: You don't download anything by hand: that's the whole point. Did you follow the steps I suggested?

Comment: @James_D i just can't click the button :).If i make the project Maven i can go back again?

Comment: You don't download the pom.  It's `pom.xml`, in the root folder of a maven project.  It tells maven the dependencies of your project, how to build your project, etc.  One of its purposes is, as James_D indicates, that you don't need to manually download any jar anymore; maven will do it for you.  If you'd want to tho, you can manually download the jfxtras jars from [maven central](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/jfxtras/)
When I answered, I assumed your project was a maven project, since you used the maven tag.  If it isn't a maven project, James_D told you how to turn it into one.

Comment: "I just can't click the button". What on earth does that mean?

Comment: @James_D It means "If i make my project Maven Project i go back to Simple Java Project again?"

Comment: Yes, just right-click, choose "Maven", "disable maven nature" (and delete the pom.xml if you want). But configuring it as a Maven project doesn't change anything about your final product, Maven is just a tool for managing dependencies and the build process.

Comment: @James_D I have done all that.But now from nowhere the project doesn't work.I have added 2 pictures in the question.As you can see the src folder classes doesn't recognize the other source folders classes.I mean i can't import them as before.I dind't changed anything just it doesn't work.

Comment: Looks like you have a non-standard setup. Right click the project, go to "Properties", "Java Build Path" and look at the "Source" tab. You may have to add those other source folders.

Comment: @James_D I uploaded an image from the tab.Everything seems good(i mean in the tab).If i disable Maven Nature i get the same errors again.It might be a bug?

Comment: Going on the link for snapshots for example if you follow jfxtras-all/8.0-r6-SNAPSHOT/ then you scroll down to find a jar.Finding one and downloading the jar is empty it contains only Meta-Inf.And the Maven has some erros as i discussed with James_D.

Comment: Aye, download the jars for the individual packages, like jfxtras-agenda etc.  I guess (but am not sure) the jfxtras-all package just references the individual jars.